# docker-compose multi-network private and internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need my container (local grpc_alpine) to have internet access whilst connected to a internal network. I have tried the following yaml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  gr1:
    image: grpc_alpine
    hostname: gr1
    container_name: gr1
    privileged: true
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/assets/grpc:/etc/grpc"
    networks:
      - default
      - mynet:
          ipv4_address: "10.10.10.11"
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_GATEWAY=10.10.10.254


networks:

  mynet:
    ipam:
      config:
          - subnet: 10.10.10.0/24
            gateway: 10.10.10.254
```

but throws this issue:

> compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files:
>   ./docker-compose.yml ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: The Compose file
>   './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: services.gr1.networks
>   contains {"mynet": {"ipv4_address": "10.10.10.11"}}, which is an
>   invalid type, it should be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small issue with your yaml configuration. The `networks` option in `services` expects a map rather than a list. Try this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  gr1:
    image: grpc_alpine
    hostname: gr1
    container_name: gr1
    privileged: true
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}/assets/grpc:/etc/grpc"
    networks:
      default:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: "10.10.10.11"
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_GATEWAY=10.10.10.254

networks:
  mynet:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.10.0/24
          gateway: 10.10.10.254
```